# Tkinter freezes when I use wait_window()

Tags: python, tkinter, window, wait

I'm trying to get some values using Tkinter GUI, for then use them to make a url request. But I got stuck apparently when a "wait_window()" command is executed, the window freezes, and if I don't use the wait_window() command, it does not return the values that i want, instead returns zeros.
Please tell me where I'm wrong, it's really frustrating. And my apologies if is an obvious mistake i'm new in tkinter.
This is my code so far, using Python 2.7.xx
Ps. when I run this code isolated it works perfectly. the problem comes when I try to mix it with the other part of my code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
def getTime(root):
    tk.Label(root,font = ('arial',12,'bold'),
         text="Input the requested values",
         fg="Steel Blue",bd=8, anchor='center').grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
    #
    tk.Label(root, text="Time (hh)"
         ).grid(row=2, column=1)    
    tk.Label(root, text="Minutes (mm)"
         ).grid(row=2, column=2)
    tk.Label(root, text="(max. 20 minutes)"
         ).grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)
    tk.Label(root, text="Lapse (min)"
         ).grid(row=4, sticky='w')
    #
    f1 = tk.IntVar()
    f2 = tk.IntVar()
    f3 = tk.IntVar()
    e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f1, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f2, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f3, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    #
    e1.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    #
    tk.Button(root, text="Done", font=('arial',10,'bold'),
              command=root.quit).grid(row=10, column=3, sticky='w')
    ##
    root.wait_window() ## here's where it stops
    ##
    return ["%02i" %f1.get(), "%02i"%f2.get(), "%02i" %f3.get()]
    #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## Some code to get other values
    ##
    root = tk.Tk()
    values = getTime(root)
    root.mainloop()  ## here stops

    print time ## never print this
    #
    time = "%s:%s" %(values[0],values[1])
    lapse = values[2]
    print time, lapse
    ##
    ## some code that will use those values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wait_window()` is something else. You want `mainloop()`.

```
import Tkinter as tk
def getTime():
    root = tk.Tk()

    tk.Label(root,font = ('arial',12,'bold'),
         text="Input the requested values",
         fg="Steel Blue",bd=8, anchor='center').grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
    #
    tk.Label(root, text="Time (hh)"
         ).grid(row=2, column=1)
    tk.Label(root, text="Minutes (mm)"
         ).grid(row=2, column=2)
    tk.Label(root, text="(max. 20 minutes)"
         ).grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)
    tk.Label(root, text="Lapse (min)"
         ).grid(row=4, sticky='w')
    #
    f1 = tk.IntVar(root)
    f2 = tk.IntVar(root)
    f3 = tk.IntVar(root)
    e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f1, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f2, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=f3, width=12,
              bg='light blue')
    #
    e1.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    #
    tk.Button(root, text="Done", font=('arial',10,'bold'),
              command=root.quit).grid(row=10, column=3, sticky='w')
    ##
    root.mainloop() ## here's where it stops
    ##
    return ["%02i" %f1.get(), "%02i"%f2.get(), "%02i" %f3.get()]
    #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## Some code to get other values
    ##
    values = getTime()

    time = "%s:%s" %(values[0],values[1])
    lapse = values[2]
    print time, lapse
```

Also, if you plan on calling this more than once, it's very important that you provide the IntVar with a master.

Comment: I have done what you said, but as I mentioned before if I don't use the wait_window() command the function returns zeros instead of the "Entry" values that I want. So running my script using only the mainloop() returns me [0,0,0]. Regarding the master i should use with the IntVar, i don't quite understand that, could you please explain it.

Comment: I gave you a version with these changes implemented. Did you try my version? It uses `mainloop` in the proper place so that the values are returned, and it provides the correct master to the IntVars.